# Minimum number of operations to make pair sums of array equal

Tags: arrays, algorithm

You are given a list of integers nums of even length. Consider an operation where you pick any number in nums and update it with a value between [1, max(nums)]. Return the number of operations required such that for every i, nums[i] + nums[n - 1 - i] equals to the same number. The problem can be solved greedily.

Note: n is the size of the array and max(nums) is the maximum element in nums.

For example: nums = [1,5,4,5,9,3] the expected operations are 2.

Explanation: The maxnums is 9, so I can change any element of nums to any number between [1, 9] which costs one operation.

- Choose 1 at index 0 and change it to 6
- Choose 9 at index 4 and change it to 4.

Now this makes the nums[0] + nums[5] = nums[1] + nums[4] = nums[2] + nums[3] = 9. We had changed 2 numbers and it cost us 2 operations which is the minimum for this input.

---

The approach that I've used is to find the median of the sums and use that to find the number of operations greedily.
Let us find the all the sums of the array based on the given condition.

- Sums can be calculated by nums[i] + nums[n-1-i].
- Let i = 0, nums[0] + nums[6-1-0] = 4.
- i = 1, nums[1] + nums[6-1-1] = 14.
- i = 2, nums[2] + nums[6-1-2] = 9.

Store these sums in an array and sort it.
sums = [4,9,14] after sorting. Now find the median from sums which is 9 as it is the middle element.

Now I use this median to equalize the sums and we can find the number of operations. I've also added the code that I use to calculate the number of operations.

```
int operations = 0;
for(int i=0; i<nums.size()/2; i++) {
    if(nums[i] + nums[nums.size()-1-i] == mid)
        continue;
        
    if(nums[i] + nums[nums.size()-1-i] > mid) {
        if(nums[i] + 1 <= mid || 1 + nums[nums.size()-1-i] <= mid) {
            operations++;
        } else {
            operations += 2;
        }
    } else if (maxnums + nums[nums.size()-1-i] >= mid || nums[i] + maxnums >= mid) {
        operations++;
    } else {
        operations += 2;
    }
}
```

The total operations for this example is 2 which is correct.

The problem here is that, for some cases choosing the median gives the wrong result. For example, the nums = [10, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 10, 8] expects 5 operations but my code gives 6 if the median (16) was chosen.

Is choosing the median not the most optimal approach? Can anyone help provide a better approach?

Comment: I don't understand the requirements.  You would have to take me step by step through the transformation of  [1,5,4,5,9,3], as an example.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I've added some explanation to the example. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Why the median? Wouldn't the mode be more useful, i.e. the sum that appears most often, meaning most number-pairs do not have to be adapted?

Comment: @tobias_k For nums =  [10, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 10, 8], the sums are [5, 5, 16, 17, 18] and if 5 is chosen as it appears twice, the number of operations are still 6. How? (10 + 8 > 5) (7 + 10 > 5) (9 + 7 > 5) all needs 2 operations each to change and make the sum equal to 5, thus making a total of 6 operations.

Comment: Well, I don't know of a proof or something, but taking the median seems reasonable because it seems like it is the closest possible value to all the other elements of sum.

Comment: I've been playing around with code, and I don't see how you modify [10, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 10, 8] with 5 operations?  I keep getting 6 operations.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc If you choose 11 as the value to equalize the sums, then you get 5 operations. In fact you can actually pick 9,10,11,12 or 13 which all will give 5 operations. And also check out tobias_k's answer which works for all the inputs.

Comment: You said we can alter any starting value from 1 to max(nums). Can any of the starting values be negative?

Answer (score 3):

I think the following should work:

- iterate pairs of numbers
- for each pair, calculate the sum of that pair, as well as the min and max sum that can be achieved by changing just *one* of the values
- update a dictionary/map with -1 when starting a new "region" requiring one fewer change, and +1 when that region is over
- iterate the boundaries in that dictionary and update the total changes needed to find the sum that requires the fewest updates

Example code in Python, giving `9` as the best sum for your example, requiring `5` changes.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

nums = [10, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 10, 8]
m = max(nums)
pairs = [(nums[i], nums[-1-i]) for i in range(len(nums)//2)]
print(pairs)

score = defaultdict(int)
for a, b in map(sorted, pairs):
    low = a + 1
    high = m + b
    score[low] -= 1
    score[a+b] -= 1
    score[a+b+1] += 1
    score[high+1] += 1
print(sorted(score.items()))

cur = best = len(nums)
num = None
for i in sorted(score):
    cur += score[i]
    print(i, cur)
    if cur < best:
        best, num = cur, i
print(best, num)
```

The total complexity of this should be O(nlogn), needing O(n) to create the dictionary, O(nlogn) for sorting, and O(n) for iterating the sorted values in that dictionary. (Do *not* use an array or the complexity could be much higher if `max(nums) >> len(nums)`)

Comment: Are you sorting in O(N) ?

Comment: @SamSegers Good catch, O(nlogn) then.

Comment: How does the iteration over score guarantee that curr reflects all the changes needed? (best is updated per single score but curr only reflects previously seen pairs. What if some pair's range starts after current?)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Not sure I understand you question. `score`, by construction, includes all the "boundaries" where a pair's "need only one/zero change" regions start or end. And `cur` is updated for each value in `score`, i.e. all changes. Did I miss something?

Comment: What is `num` in `print(best, num)`?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Badly chosen name. It's the best sum, `9` in this case if I remember correct.y

Comment: I think I get it now. Since, in your routine, we start out assuming all numbers need to change, we gradually update that to the best we can.

Answer (score 2):

*(UPDATED receiving additional information)*

**The optimal sum** must be one of the following:

- a sum of a pair -> because you can keep both numbers of that pair
- the min value of a pair + 1 -> because it is the smallest possible sum you only need to change 1 of the numbers for that pair
- the max value of a pair + the max overall value -> because it is the largest possible sum you only need to change 1 of the numbers for that pair

> Hence, there are order N possible sums.

**The total number of operations** for this optimal sum can be calculated in various ways.

The **O(N²)** is quite trivial. And you can implement it quite easily if you want to confirm other solutions work.

Making it **O(N log N)**

- getting all possible optimal sums **O(N)**
- for each possible sum you can calculate **occ** the number of pairs having that exact sum and thus don't require any manipulation. **O(N)**
- For all other pairs you just need to know if it requires 1 or 2 operations to get to that sum. Which is 2 when it is either impossible if the smallest of the pair is too big to reach sum with the smallest possible number or when the largest of the pair is too small to reach the sum with the largest possible number. Many data structures could be used for that (BIT, Tree, ..). I just used a sorted list and applied binary search (not exhaustively tested though). **O(N log N)**

Example solution in java:

```
int[] nums = new int[] {10, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 10, 8};
// preprocess pairs: O(N)
int min = 1
    , max = nums[0];
List<Integer> minList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> maxList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer, Integer> occ = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0;i<nums.length/2;i++) {
    int curMin = Math.min(nums[i], nums[nums.length-1-i]);
    int curMax = Math.max(nums[i], nums[nums.length-1-i]);
    min = Math.min(min, curMin);
    max = Math.max(max, curMax);
    minList.add(curMin);
    maxList.add(curMax);
    // create all pair sums
    int pairSum = nums[i] + nums[nums.length-1-i];
    int currentOccurences = occ.getOrDefault(pairSum, 0);
    occ.put(pairSum, currentOccurences + 1);
}
// sorting 0(N log N)
Collections.sort(minList);
Collections.sort(maxList);
// border cases 
for (int a : minList) {
    occ.putIfAbsent(a + max, 0);
}
for (int a : maxList) {
    occ.putIfAbsent(a + min, 0);
}

// loop over all condidates O(N log N)
int best = (nums.length-2);
int med = max + min;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : occ.entrySet()) {
    int sum = entry.getKey();
    int count = entry.getValue();
    int requiredChanges = (nums.length / 2) - count;
    if (sum > med) {
        // border case where max of pair is too small to be changed to pair of sum
        requiredChanges += countSmaller(maxList, sum - max);
    } else if (sum < med) {
        // border case where having a min of pair is too big to be changed to pair of sum
        requiredChanges += countGreater(minList, sum - min);
    }
    System.out.println(sum + " -> " + requiredChanges);
    best = Math.min(best, requiredChanges);
}
System.out.println("Result: " + best);
}

// O(log N)
private static int countGreater(List<Integer> list, int key) {
 int low=0, high=list.size();
 while(low < high) {
     int mid = (low + high) / 2;
     if (list.get(mid) <= key) {
        low = mid + 1;
    } else {
        high = mid;
    }
 }
 return list.size() - low;
}

// O(log N)
private static int countSmaller(List<Integer> list, int key) {
 int low=0, high=list.size();
 while(low < high) {
     int mid = (low + high) / 2;
     if (list.get(mid) < key) {
        low = mid + 1;
    } else {
        high = mid;
    }
 }
 return low;
}
```

Comment: That was my first idea, too, but it does not work if the most-common sum is _less_ than the smaller number of one of the other pairs.

Comment: Yeah, I only read the first part of the question when I started on this. Updated it now with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer some theory -- we can easily show that the upper bound for needed changes is `n / 2`, where `n` is the number of elements. This is because each pair can be made in *one* change to anything between `1 + C` and `max(nums) + C`, where `C` is any of the two elements in a pair. For the smallest `C`, we can bind `max(nums) + 1` at the highest; and for the largest `C`, we can bind `1 + max(nums)` at the lowest.

Since those two bounds at the worst cases are equal, we are guaranteed there is some solution with at most `N / 2` changes that leaves at least one `C` (array element) unchanged.

From that we conclude that an optimal solution either (1) has at least one pair where neither element is changed and the rest require only one change per pair, or (2) our optimal solution has `n / 2` changes as discussed above.

We can therefore proceed to test each existing pair's single or zero change possibilities as candidates. We can iterate over a sorted list of two to three possibilities per pair, labeled with each cost and index. (Other authors on this page have offered similar ways and code.)